# How can i use template in valid way in this case?

Tags: c++, templates

I do not understand what is the reason for this problem that i got in the next code, what is not ok?

The **error** messages:

> (1) Invalid template arguments
>   (2) Invalid template arguments
>   (3) mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template class MyClass'

```
template<typename Data, typename KeyType, typename CompareFunction>
class MyClass{
private:
    MyClass* user;
    Data data;
    KeyType key;
    CompareFunction cmpFunction;

public:
    MyClass(KeyType key, Data data, CompareFunction cmpFunction);
...
};  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool CMP(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}

int main{
MyClass<int, int, CMP> *my_class= new MyClass<int, int, CMP>(2, 3); // ALL THE 
                                                                    //  ERRORS
...
...
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep reading the error message.  You should have a line that says something like `main.cpp:24:22: note:   expected a type, got 'CMP'`

Comment: Downvoted because this is not your real code. All the `...` and the missing parentheses in `main` serve only to hide the real issues with the code. **Do not post pseudo code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So... You cannot do that with functions. In c++ function is not a first-class object. What you can pass as a template parameter are only build-in types and classes.
However you can simulate passing a function in two ways:

1) pass an object called a *functor* (that is, an object with overloaded () operator)

2) pass a *lambda expression* (kind of a dynamic function)

Below are the two approaches demonstrated:

```
template<typename Data, typename KeyType, typename CompareFunction>
class MyClass {

private:
    MyClass *user;
    Data data;
    KeyType key;
    CompareFunction cmpFunction;

public:
    MyClass(KeyType key, Data data, CompareFunction cmpFunction) :
            key(key), data(data), cmpFunction(cmpFunction) {}
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// 1) Functor class
class CMP {
    int operator()(int a, int b) {
        return a == b;
    }
};

// 2) Lambda expression
auto lambda_CMP = [](int a, int b) -> bool { return a == b; };

int main() {

    // 1) Using functors:
    MyClass<int, int, CMP> * my_class = new MyClass<int, int, CMP>(2, 2, CMP());

    // 2) Using lambda expression
    MyClass<int, int, decltype(lambda_CMP)> *lambda_class =
            new MyClass<int, int, decltype(lambda_CMP)>(2, 2, lambda_CMP);

}
```

**decltype** is a specifier that

> Inspects the declared type of an entity or the type and value category of an expression.
>   (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

**Note:** I had to add an initialization list to the constructor because lambda's default constructor is deleted so you have to assign it somehow in the class.

Comment: you know what is the reason for this error now ? "undefined reference to `MyClass<int, int, CMP>::MyClass(int, int, CMP)'"

Comment: Did you copy all of my code? Because I've spotted a mistake in yours. You missed the parenthesis () after the int main. It might be the cause.